# Method to refactor the loop in Python?

Tags: python, loops, refactoring

For example, there're two similar codes:

The first one is:

```
 for chrom in bins:
     for a_bin in bins[chrom]:
         for pos in a_bin:
             pos = pos+100
```

The second one is:

```
 for chrom in bins:
     for a_bin in bins[chrom]:
         for pos in a_bin:
             if chrom=="chr1":
                 pos = pos*100
```

I was wondering that whether there's a way to refactor the loop so that I don't need to repeat writing code with the same structure..

Anyone has ideas about this?

Comment: note: `pos = ..` has no effect on `bins` and `pos` refers to the next object in `a_bin` on every iteration

Comment: Can you provide some context as to what you are trying to do because as its written your loop doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved with a [generator function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_%28computer_science%29).

```
def gen():
    for chrom in bins:
        for a_bin in bins[chrom]:
           for pos in a_bin:
               yield pos
```

You can iterate through the items generated by `gen()`, though there is no "list of item" that is built -- rather, it is constructed on demand:

```
for pos in gen():
    pass # add loop code here
```

This also means that, if you exit the loop early, the `gen()` method will be aborted (with an exception). Take a look at [corutines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine) to understand how this is implemented.